# vhs to digital conversion flickers only when captured

Tags: vhs

I have a Diamond One Touch Video Capture.  When I view the video on my computer is is great, but when I select capture, the video and audio flicker.  These are old home videos.  I tried a commercial movie video and it didn't flicker.  I don't think it is the One Touch because the videos do not flicker when viewed on my computer, only when being captured.  The capture software is Power Director and EZ Grabber.  I have tried two different VCRs.  Diamond has sent me a second One Touch.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share a sample? NTSC or PAL? I'm assuming the tapes don't have copy protection, like Macrovision, right?

Answer (score 0):

So once captured the file plays without these issues it's only during recording ?

Or are you saying that while the video is playing from the recorder but the computer is not recording it's okay & then when you try to record it has those issues ?

It could be an incorrect field setting in the software or buffering during recording.

Have a look at the software recorders settings & see if there's something for fields "upper" or "lower" or possible even deinterlace.

Are you recording to an external drive or straight to your hard drive ? If you have the option try recording to a different drive.

And like Michael said if you upload a sample we can better see the issue